# Rails: count the click number of a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to count the number of user visiting a link in my website(http://productchaseapp.herokuapp.com/). Specificly, I want to know the click number of the `product.url` (user visiting the `external url` of a product).
This is how the link works:

```
link_to product.name, product.url, target: '_blank'
```

The problem is that, by doing this, there is no way that I can actually update the `clickCount` of the `product`, after all, after user clicks the link, they are outside of my website.

I think one solution, is to change the the link to

```
link_to product.name, product_path(product), target: '_blank'
```

And in `ProductsController#Show`, update the attribute and redirect the user outside of the website to `product.url`.

I'm not sure if this is a good solution, and what are other good ways of doing this.

Comment: Your redirect solution makes the most sense. It requires only one or two extra lines of code. I don't know anything about the gem recommended below, but I'd think that writing one line that you control is better than adding a whole gem, to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [https://ankane.github.io/ahoy/](http://ankane.github.io/ahoy/)

> Ahoy provides a solid foundation to track visits and events in Ruby,
>   JavaScript, and native apps.
>
> Works with any data store so you can easily scale.

For example, you can do:

```
ahoy.trackClicks();
```

Comment: Any tips on using this with external links?  If I track a link to an external site, it will not be registered unless I come back from the external site.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle it is to override the `click` event of the link in question to fire a `PUT` back to an endpoint in your app which tracks link clicks, then redirect to the external URL.